# How to add new request header and forward the request to new resource (URL) in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, nginx, spring-boot

I'm kind of playing around with Nginx and Microservice( developed in Spring boot). I want to know is a way to add a new value in the request header and redirect to a new resource in Nginx from one of the microservice which is running as Spring boot application. TIA

Config:

```
 server {
        listen       8091;
        server_name  localhost;
        location / {
            rewrite_by_lua_file  redirect.lua;
        }
        location /authdone/ {
            rewrite_by_lua_file  redirect.lua;
        }

        location /authorize/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }

        location /admin/ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
     include nginx_backend.conf;
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes there is a way, but you should post the config that you have tried

Comment: Hello Tarun, Thank you so much for your response.

see the question for the config I have been using. I'm using the Lua script to verify the token present in the request header and trying to redirect it to the microservice. But, In my case, the value is not getting set in the request header.

Comment: Did you try setting the `Location: <url>` header? From your question and details you posted it is still unclear as to what you want

Comment: I understand that I framed my question very badly. Apologies!
 I was checking whether is it possible for Nginx to redirect to the actual page once it authenticates the request. Like for e.g. nginx is listening to port 8080. If I request for http://localhost:8080/service1, before forwarding the request to service1, nginx should prompt the user to authenticate using a login screen say http://localhost:8080/login, after successful auth, nginx should automatically forward the request to  http://localhost:8080/service1. TIA

Comment: Have you looked at the `auth_request` directive? https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html. I think you can use that and the redirect will require you to add a return url

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It helped me.